# Difficulty in deciding where to put the code in yii view helper

Tags: yii

I'm new to yii development.

In my system I'm trying to create a submenu system. The submenu will be shown based on the 
controller. The submenu will be separate views, that I'll load in main layout.

I want to separate the logic of loading the submenu view from the main layout. But, I'm not sure where to write it.

Does Yii has view helpers like in RoR. Or, should I write it as a component?

Please give suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just create a component for this, and instantiate that with the relevant menu options from the controllers. If present in all controllers, implement support in a BaseController and just set up an array of items in the child controllers.

Answer (score 1):

Your default generated Yii application has a parent Controller in protected/components/Controller.php. If you need to access additional parameters in layout, add public properties to Controller, set them in your child controller, and use them in your view/layout files.

In your case, add a function to this parent Controller that returns a rendered submenu (with a renderPartial call for example) and call this function from your layout.